# issue with image_tag when using html in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I need to insert a part of the html inside an existing html block so I am trying first to create this html and as it will be used in many places hence I am using an helper to create this fragment
But the image_tag is throwing errors and it works perfectly if directly used in the view

my helper code

```
def create_banner_html_helper(banner)

    if banner.logo.present?
      return "<div class='m3-news_wrap m3-mdcast-banner slide'>
    <a href='" + banner.link_url + "' target=_'blank'>
    <div class='m3-article'>

<div class='m3-section m3-img_holder'>"
      image_tag banner.logo(:small)
      "</div>
    <div class='m3-section m3-desc'>
         <h3 class='m3-title'>" + banner.title+ "</h3>
                    <p>" + banner.subtitle + "</p>
         <a href='" + banner.link_url + "' target='_blank'>" + banner.link_text + "</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>".html_safe

    end

    return "<div class='m3-news_wrap m3-mdcast-banner slide'>
    <a href='" + banner.link_url + "' target=_'blank'>
    <div class='m3-article'>

    <div class='m3-section m3-desc'>
         <h3 class='m3-title'>" + banner.title+ "</h3>
                    <p>" + banner.subtitle + "</p>
         <a href='" + banner.link_url + "' target='_blank'>" + banner.link_text + "</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>".html_safe
  end
```

banner passed is an ActiveRecord object.

I really don't know what is the issue so any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: what's the error it's throwing

Comment: right now it is printing only the second half of the code after the image_tag div.. I am not getting the error but it ain't showing the top part at all.. but it is displaying the HTML as is without rendering it as HTML

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to `concat` and / or `capture` the elements, otherwise only the last section will be returned.

There's a good link to it here: https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/
Or the official docs here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat

There's a capture block used in the linked article that has the following code:

```
module MyHelper
  def widget
    capture do
      concat link_to("Hello", hello_path)
      concat " "
      concat link_to("Bye", goodbye_path)
    end
  end
end
```

Stating:

> You can get around this with the capture helper. That’s what
>   content_tag uses internally: capture, true to its name, captures the
>   content so it isn’t appended straight to the page. Instead, it’s built
>   up as a separate string, for your custom helper to return (or have its
>   way with)

I'd wrap your code like this - concatenating the string elements and the image tag, the return the entirety.

**Edit: N.B. I think a quick `+` either side of the `image_tag` would solve this, and perhaps be a lot easier :)**

Like this perhaps?

```
    if banner.logo.present?
      return "<div class='m3-news_wrap m3-mdcast-banner slide'>
                <a href='" + banner.link_url + "' target=_'blank'>
                  <div class='m3-article'>

                    <div class='m3-section m3-img_holder'>" +
                      image_tag(banner.logo(:small)) +
                    "</div>
                    <div class='m3-section m3-desc'>
                      <h3 class='m3-title'>" + banner.title + "</h3>
                      <p>" + banner.subtitle + "</p>
                      <a href='" + banner.link_url + "' target='_blank'>" + banner.link_text + "</a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </a>
             </div>".html_safe

    end
```

(FYI I think you were missing a final closing `div` in there.)

Comment: not able to get it to work.. It would be really helpful if you can write this helper code for me..just the if part will be fine as I will manage the else part myself.. Thanking you in advance

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version using my update, aka a couple more `+`s.

Having a bit of a think on this - would this not be better sitting in a partial, rendered as and where needed with the banner passed in? I.E. `<%= render 'banner', banner: banner %>` (@DivXZero has answered with the same as I typed.)

Comment: actually this html will sit between 2 other html blocks which will be then displayed.. so I am also confused as to what will be the best way. I am new to this so not really sure.. what is your take on the situation?

Comment: the code is giving error.. /Users/dhavalchheda/Projects/M3India_App/m3india_app/app/helpers/frontend/contents_helper.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' image_tag banner.logo(:small) + ^ /Users/dhavalchheda/Projects/M3India_App/m3india_app/app/helpers/frontend/contents_helper.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' image_tag banner.logo(:small) + ^

Comment: Hey - I'd edit that comment to remove the personal info in the error paths :) That sounds like a typo / code issue somewhere in there. I'd recommend switching across to contain this in a partial ((docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). I've got to dash for now - but hope that helps and with a little more time you'll get this working!

Comment: Ah - one final edit: I think the image tag needs its parameter wrapped in parenthesis. Answer updated @DhavalChheda. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when you are calling image_tag, it's essentially calling return, which is going to end the execution of the rest of your method (hence why it stops outputting there).

I would suggest moving all of the html from your helper into a partial. Pass any variables you need as locals. This will help with readability and maintainability of your code.

Partial to replace your helper (Let's say it's views/partials/_banner_logo.html.erb):

```
<div class='m3-news_wrap m3-mdcast-banner slide'>
  <a href='<%= banner.link_url %>' target=_'blank'>
    <div class='m3-article'>
      <% if banner.logo.present? %>
        <div class='m3-section m3-img_holder'>
          <%= image_tag banner.logo(:small) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class='m3-section m3-desc'>
        <h3 class='m3-title'><%= banner.title %></h3>
        <p><%= banner.subtitle %></p>
        <a href='<%= banner.link_url %>' target='_blank'><%= banner.link_text %></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

To use it, call render from whatever view/template you need it rendered in and pass the banner:

```
<%= render 'partials/banner_logo', banner: your_banner_variable %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your method with

```
<%= create_banner_html_helper(banner).html_safe %>
```

It should fix your problem of printing it directly as a string instead of html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your efforts but I wanted to keep my view file clean and hence I put this code in a helper..

This is the code I am using and it might help somebody in future..

```
banner_logo_snippet = if self.logo.present?
        "<div class='m3-section m3-img_holder'><img src='#{self.logo(:small)}' /></div>"
      else
        ''
      end
      banner_snippet = <<"END"
  <div class="m3-news_wrap m3-mdcast-self slide" style="border: 1px solid ##{self.border_color}; background-color: ##{self.background_color};">
  <a href="#{self.link_url}" target="_blank">
    <div class="m3-article">
      #{banner_logo_snippet}
      <div class='m3-section m3-desc'>
        <h3 class='m3-title'>#{self.title}</h3>
        <p>#{self.subtitle}</p>
        <a href="#{self.link_url}" target="_blank">#{self.link_text}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
END
```

Thank you everybody for your time and cheers to the community..
Take care and happy coding